# UISegmentedControl not receiving touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

Here's my code:

```
UISegmentedControl* scTopNav = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Show Comparison", @"Estimated Annual Units", nil]];
[scTopNav setFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-(scTopNav.frame.size.width/2), vUserInputs.frame.origin.y + vUserInputs.frame.size.height + 50.0, scTopNav.frame.size.width, scTopNav.frame.size.height)];
[scTopNav addTarget:self action:@selector(navOptions:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
scTopNav.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;

[self.view addSubview:scTopNav];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:scTopNav];
```

the control doesn't highlight when touched nor does the navOptions method get called. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Is another view occluding self.view or scTopNav? You can use `po [view recursiveDescription]` to have the debugger spew out frames so you can debug such overlap issues.

Comment: No, but just to be safe I brought the UISC to the front.

Comment: You will have to debug the view hierarchy to see if someone is occluding self.view. Or if a super has userInteractionEnabled set to NO.

Comment: Have you checked what the frame size actually is?

Comment: Dang - I'm going to right now but I want to put my chips down that that is probably it - w/h are going to be 0.0...brb

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it, here's the frame from my log : 2013-06-25 11:56:38.735 oer[13825:c07] {{166.5, 310}, {435, 44}}

Comment: Solved it, it was an overlapping view issue, even with me bringing it to the front...thanks for the assist...Sanjit, post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I just put my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is another view occluding `self.view` or `scTopNav`? You can use `po [view recursiveDescription]` to have the debugger spew out frames so you can debug such overlap issues.